# JFrame not updating graphics from a separate class

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe

I am running into a strange problem I cannot solve. I have two classes a JFrame class:

```
public class TowerDefenceFrame extends JFrame {

public TowerDefenceFrame() {
    super("Tower Defence");
    setSize(1023, 708);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //setResizable(false);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    TowerDefenceFrame tdf = new TowerDefenceFrame();
    tdf.setVisible(true);
    Map.main(args);
  }
}
```

and a graphics class:

```
public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
BufferedImage road;
BufferedImage grass;
Timer time;

public Board() {
    setFocusable(true);
    time = new Timer(5, this);
    time.start();

    try {
        road = ImageIO.read(new File("../road.png"));
        grass = ImageIO.read(new File("../grass.png"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Board.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    repaint();

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
     super.paint(g);

        for (int i = 0; i <= Map.mapWidth - 1; i++) {
            for (int l = 0; l <= Map.mapHeight - 1; l++) {

            if (Map.mapArray[l][i] == 1) {
                g.drawImage(road, (Map.blockSize * i), (Map.blockSize * l), this);

            } else if (Map.mapArray[l][i] == 0) {
                g.drawImage(grass,(Map.blockSize * i), (Map.blockSize * l), this);
            } 

        }





    }
         repaint();

   }
}
```

When I run the application the JFrame appears, however the graphics from the Board class do not. I was looking for answers to this problem and couldn't find one. I noticed that when I resized the JFrame the images from the board class appeared. This led me to believe that I had to update the board class to get the graphics. I tried adding a timer loop in my JFrame class to add the Board class every 1/2 second. It didn't work. I have been stumped on this problem for a while and I'm wondering if any of you could help out,

Thanks.

Comment: The method to override is paintComponent(Graphics). ANd all the swing components should only be used from the event dispatch thread, and not from the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes that start with `J` such as `JApplet` and `JFrame` are `Swing`, and `Applet` and `Frame` are `AWT`.  The method `paint()` is used with the `AWT` class, yet you are using `JPanel`s and `JFrame`s.

Also, because you call `super` in your `paint()` method (which you will change to `paintComponent`), you have to `@Override` for it to work properly.

Comment: I would like to continue using Swing, how would I use a Swing equivalent of paint? Thanks for your help, Nick.

Comment: @NickHaughton `paintComponent` is `Swing`.

Comment: I implemented the code changes you suggested, however i still get the same error:
[here's the updated code](http://pastebin.com/9TLP1q11)

Comment: @syb0rg: you don't need to use Override to override a method. Override is used to let the compiler know that your intention is to override a method. And calling super.paint() or not doesn't change anything.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @syb0rg and JB Nizet I finally figured it out. The order I was executing my code in prevented the information the graphics required to load in time for it to be displayed. Thank you for teaching me more about AWT and Swing,
Nick